# Protein content in chemical composition of different phyla?

Tags: cell-biology, proteins, plant-physiology, phylogenetics

The protein content in the human body is roughly 15%, what are the percentages for other organisms? Bacteria, plants, fungi, protozoa, etc.

Comment: It can vary greatly and what you are asking is a shopping list of different values.
A spore is very high in protein. _Bacillus subtilis_ (you may have seen slime on old bacon?) is by weight mostly carbohydrate (i.e. slime). etc.

Comment: Also, 'Bacteria, plants, fungi, protozoa, etc.' are not phyla. A phyla is a rank between kingdom and class. What you mean is clade or phylogenetic group —'protozoa' are not a clade (polyphyletic).

Comment: phylogenetic group and phyla are interchangeable, depending on semantic framework you use (they describe large clades, if you prefer word clade), but clade works as word. yes protozoa are polyphyletic.